# Check which radio buttons is Selected in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can anybody help me in getting the values from a set of radio buttons in AngularJS. 
Certain conditions have to be executed one the radio button is selected

Eg : Female & Male  if female is selected  it should show them belle classes if male is selected it should show Judo classes

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: Its fixed there was typo in the ng-model value

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.color = 'blue';
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "id": "12345",
        "value": "green"
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">  Red <br/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" ng-value="specialValue"> Green <br/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
  <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Note that `ng-value="specialValue"` sets radio item's value to be the value of `$scope.specialValue`.